# Omniauth making multiple auth calls per request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I have Omniauth set up with a WePay strategy ( https://github.com/intridea/omniauth ). When getting authorization, it is making the `v2/oauth2/token` call four times (interspersed with `/v2/user` calls), but returns on the first access token in the `env["omniauth.auth"]` variable. This results in both long load times on the callback and a "access_token revoked" error when trying to perform an API call later.

I'm completely flummoxed as to why this is happening. I've tried disabling every method that follows the callback, so I'm pretty sure this is happening within Omniauth itself, as opposed to my app (which is in Rails, btw).

Here's my `omniauth.rb` initializer file:

```
require "omniauth/strategies/wepay"
 OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :wepay, ENV['WEPAY_STAGE_APP_ID'], ENV['WEPAY_STAGE_SECRET']
   provider :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
   provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET']
 end
```

Relevant routes:

```
match 'auth/wepay/callback', to: 'sessions#wepay'
match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/organization')
```

The sessions controller (though I am reasonably confident the loop is happening before this ever gets called):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_all_organizations
  before_filter :authorize_current_organization

  def wepay
    current_user.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @organization.wepay_account_id? == false
      @organization.create_wepay_account(current_user)
    end

    redirect_to transactions_path, notice: 'Login successful.' 
  end
end
```

The relevant section of my log:

```
Started GET "/auth/wepay/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-26 17:40:18 -0700
(wepay) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/auth/wepay/callback?code=XXXXX&state=XXXXX" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-26 17:40:25 -0700
(wepay) Callback phase initiated.
Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-6.newrelic.com
Processing by SessionsController#wepay as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"XXXXX", "state"=>"XXXXX"}
```

I'm having a tough time debugging this, but New Relic does show that 548ms are being spent in `sessions#wepay`, vs 261ms in `Net::HTTP[stage.wepayapi.com]: POST`. I don't know if that's indicative of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Cool, just checking. On my end, as a test, I just ran the gem through a couple of Rails Omniauth premade apps, both of which were easily able to authenticate and return back to the app. I used these to create the apps:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/
and
http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-mongoid-omniauth.html

I would check the session controller code, as it may not just be a routing issue.

Comment: Hm... Well, I realized my Facebook testing my be giving a false positive, since it doesn't give a new access token for each auth call. Do you know of any good way to try and debug this? I've commented out everything in the controller method, so i'm a little stumped as to how to debug this.